# Powershell change file lastmodified with date taken

Tags: powershell, directory

I've already got a part of the script done, I'm just missing a tiny part that happens to be the biggest issue for me..

```
Get-ChildItem -force C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxx\test\ * | ForEach-Object{$_.LastWriteTime = (?????)
```

$*.CreationTime and $*.LastWriteTime have nothing to do with date taken, I've already tried that in the (?????)

basically I need a script to replace the datelastwrite with datetaken for every file in the directory...

Comment: "date taken" isn't a native file-system property; it sounds like you're dealing with _photo_ files whose _embedded metadata_ contains this information; if so, please clarify what types of files you're dealing with, on what platform.

Comment: pictures, I know it's possible to replace a part of the code with something that gets specific metadata type and retrieves it. I just don't know how

Comment: You might want to consult this Scripting Guy Blog posting: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/